# Issues with fancybox .iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have issues when trying to display a YouTube file using the fancybox iframe. It displays a small frame with a scroller. I have attached a link to the code. I am using the YouTube API to extract the content.

https://jsfiddle.net/Le98zx1s/

jQuery displaying to html

```
function getOutput (item)
{
    var videoId = item.id.videoId;
    var title = item.snippet.title;
    var description = item.snippet.description;
    var thumb = item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url;
    var channelTitle = item.snippet.channelTitle;
    var videoDate = item.snippet.publishedAt;
    var output = '<li>' +
                     '<div class = "list-left">' +
                         '<img src="' + thumb + '">' +
                     '</div>' +
                     '<div class ="list-right">' +
                         '<h3><a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe"' + 'href="http://youtube.com/embed/' + videoId + '">' + title + '</a></h3>' +
                         '<small>By <span class="cTitle">' + channelTitle + '</span> on ' + videoDate + '</small>' +
                         '<p>' + description+'</p>' +
                     '</div>' +
                 '</li>' +
                 '<div class ="clearfix"></div>' + ' ';
    return output;
}
```